# matplotlib figure output in a mess

Tags: matplotlib

Been trying to make a plot, but the output is a mess and there seems to be no problem with the code. Can anyone help explain this?

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7khkD.png)

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.sin(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(111)
ax[0].plot(x, y)
plt.show()
fig.savefig("1.png")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing `plt.subplots(111)`?

Comment: I was trying to make a plt.subplots(311) but it was a mess too, so reverted to 111 only to test out.

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, *, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None, **fig_kw)` What you are doing is passing 111 rows of subplots here

Comment: I guess you are trying to use `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(*args, **kwargs)` or `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(nrows, ncols, index, **kwargs)`. You can check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `plt.subplots(111)`. You are passing 111 number of rows in: `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, *, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None, **fig_kw)`
If you just want a single graph, you can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.sin(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output Graph]

**Did you mean to use `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot(*args, **kwargs)`?**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.subplot(111)
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

**Another Example using `plt.subplot(311)`:**

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.subplot(311)
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(x,y,c='red')
plt.show()
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax2.plot(x,y,c='green')
plt.show()
ax2 = plt.subplot(3,1,1)
ax2.plot(x,y,c='blue')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: (311) plot]

Comment: this still doesn't solve the multiplot questions i want to do, same mess is produced when i tried to use fig, ax = plt.subplots(311)
ax[0].plot()
ax[1].plot()
ax[2].plot()

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(311)` produces 311 rows of empty plots in a single figure where you are only filling `ax[0].plot()`. The other 310 rows are empty plots. Do you want these empty plots?